# Programmatically scroll inactive tab to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I would like to smoothly scroll inactive Chrome tab to bottom, but it only gets scrolled when I activate the tab. Is there a way to proceed with scrolling without activating the tab?
Here is a code to test via console:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.scrollBy({
    top: 9999999,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}, 3000);
```

Insert it into console, switch to another tab, wait 3 seconds and then go back. Tab will be only scrolled after you activate it again.

Comment: A working code example would be really helpful.

Comment: @AndyHoffman working code example is inside the question, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve (smoothly scroll inactive tab is a bit weird, you can't see it anyway) but I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522580/2438933

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the scroll but the setTimeout that does not work the same if the tab is not active.